# java.lang.ShortCache.cache contained wrong value

Tags: java, jvm, short

One of my applications decided today to return 1, when

```
Short.valueOf("0")
```

was called.
I discovered, that

```
ShortCache.cache[128]
```

was set to 1 instead of 0, the other cached values were correct.

Here is how the Cache is initialized:

```
private static class ShortCache {
    private ShortCache(){}

    static final Short cache[] = new Short[-(-128) + 127 + 1];

    static {
        for(int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
            cache[i] = new Short((short)(i - 128));
    }
}
```

What are possible scenarios for this to happen?

Comment: This could happen if a malicious library or piece of code (or a colleague with a misplaced sense of humour) modified the cache, eg see [Add Some Entropy to Your JVM](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/17/add-some-entropy-to-your-jvm/)

Comment: I saw this in a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amXXYgu0eFY it seems like something is modifying the cache.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and John Mercier: That would indeed be nasty. However, since the image containing this application is running on multiple environments and this only happended once so far (and a restart fixed it), I was wondering if some non-java process in- or outside of the container could have modified the value referenced by the given Short.

Comment: Although possible, such an outside corruption would - I think -  be even less likely.